# Inno Setup CreateOleObject('IISNamespace') throws exception on Windows Server 2012

Tags: iis, inno-setup, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5, pascalscript

I am trying to create IISSetup in the Windows Server 2012 (IIS version 8.5) through the below install script but throws error "Invalid class string".
code:

```pascal
var
  IIS, WebSite, WebServer, WebRoot, VDir: Variant;
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  { Create the main IIS COM Automation object }
  try
    IIS := CreateOleObject('IISNamespace');
  except
    RaiseException(
      'Please install Microsoft IIS first.'#13#13'(Error ''' +
      GetExceptionMessage + ''' occurred)');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Does that COM object exist on Windows 2012 server, did you check?

Comment: The *"Invalid class string"* exception message you see just because you're running your setup in debugger. If you were running your setup without debugger, your *"Please install Microsoft IIS first..."* message would be shown instead in the expcetion dialog because you are swallowing all the expcetions possibly raised by that `CreateOleObject` function call.

Comment: I am having the same issue on Windows 2008 Server R2 (64 bit). Any ideas on how to fix the "invalid class string" issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with Service Pack 1.

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  iis: OleVariant;
begin
  iis := CreateOleObject('IISNamespace');
end;
```

[image: iisnamespace]

The solution for me was a missing IIS feature. One has to install the IIS 6 thingy.

(germany version, don't know english)

- IIS 6-Verwaltungskompatibilität

  - IIS 6-Metabasiskompatibilität
  - IIS 6-WMI-Kompatibilität
  - IIS 6-Scriptingtools
  - IIS 6-Verwaltungskonsole

I am not sure but "IIS 6-Scriptingtools" should be enough.

[image: iis features]