# Inno setup getting error - invalid class string progid "IISNamespace"

Tags: c#, .net-core, inno-setup

I have installed IIS but getting error 
invalid class string progid "IISNamespace"

```
 try
    IIS := CreateOleObject('IISNamespace');
  except
    RaiseException('Please install Microsoft IIS first.'#13#13'(Error ''' + GetExceptionMessage + ''' occurred)');
  end;
```

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/q/25617718/850848 ?

Comment: Thanks that helped in resolving the issue.